# I can't find the error and it's driving me crazy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax, view

This is my `index.html.erb` for `Post#index`

I get this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/posts/index.html.erb:34: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting &. or :: or '[' or '.'
```

please help!

```
<div class="title">

        <h1>All Posts</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post_list">
        <% for @posts.each do |p| %>
            <div class="post_title">
                <h2><%= p.date.strftime("%Y%m%d") %></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="post_type">
                <h3><%= p.type %></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="post_content">
                <p><%= p.content %></p>
            </div>
                <% unless p.is_cited='false' %>
                    <div class="post_citation">
                        <p><i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= p.citation %></i></p>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
                </br>
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="action_buttons">
                        <div class="show">
                            <%= link_to 'Show', @post %>  
                        </div>
                        <div class="edit">
                            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="delete">
                            <%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, :method => :delete %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            <% end %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what's causing the problem, but you're referencing @post inside your each block. Try changing

```
<%= link_to 'Show', @post %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Show', p %>
```

and change

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(@post), data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, :method => :delete %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(p), data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, :method => :delete %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the following:

`<% for @posts.each do |p| %>`

try:

`<% @posts.each do |p| %>`

Comment: That has no effect